# How to get the top row in join which is ordered by another column

Tags: sql, join

I have an inner join on 2 tables.

Consider

Table1

```
   sid   name
    1   abc
    2   xyz
```

Table2

```
sdid sid detailname
1     1    a
2     1    b
3     2    x
```

So my query looks like below

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.sid=t2.sid
```

the result i get is

```
sid  name   sdid    sid  detailname
1     abc    1       1      a
1     abc    2       1      b
2     xyz    3       2      x
```

I want to modify this query to get the highest 'sdid' from table 2

my end result should look like

```
sid    name   sdid    sid  detailname 
1       abc    2       1      b
2       xyz    3       2      x
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include one more subquery in the `join` to get the max sdid for each sid from table2.

```
SELECT t1.sid,t1.name,t2.sdid,t2.sid,t2.detailname
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.sid=t2.sid
INNER JOIN (select max(sdid) as maxsdid, sid from table2 group by sid) t21 
ON t21.sid=t2.sid and t21.sdid = t2.sdid
```